# React filter on item in array inside array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, filter, mobx

I am trying to return a filtered list in a [mobx](https://mobx.js.org/) store but I cant figure out how the filter function properly works. I have a array that looks like this

```
      @observable files = ([
        {
        id: '1',
        fileType: 'Document',
        files: [
            {
              name: 'test1',
              size: '64kb',
              date: '2018-01-19'
            },
            {
              name: 'test2',
              size: '94kb',
              date: '2018-01-19'
            }
        ]
      },
      {
      id: '2',
      fileType: 'List',
      files: [
          {
            name: 'test3',
            size: '64kb',
            date: '2018-01-19'
          },
          {
            name: 'test4',
            size: '94kb',
            date: '2018-01-19'
          },
          {
            name: 'test5',
            size: '94kb',
            date: '2018-01-19'
          }
      ]
    } and so on...
```

I want to be able to filter on all names `this.files[x].files[x].name`
and then return the result. If I set the "What to put here" to `this.files[0].files[0].name` I am able to filter on the first entry of name. But how can i filter dynamically on all names?

```
  @observable filter = ""
  @computed get filteredFiles(){
    var matchesFilter = new RegExp(this.filter, "i")
    var filtered = this.files.filter(file => !this.filter || matchesFilter.test(What to put here?))
    return filtered
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `matchesFilter.test(What to put here?)` to

```
file.files.some(nestedfile=>matchesFilter.test(nestedFile.name))
```

---

if you want to also filter the inner list of files to only those that match then you need to `.map` the array

```js
var filtered = this.files
  .filter(file =>
    !this.filter || file.files.some(nestedfile => matchesFilter.test(nestedFile.name)))
  .map(file => ({ ...file,
    files: file.files.filter(nesstedFile => matchesFilter.test(nestedFile.name))
  }));
```

Comment: I still have some problems with the filter, it returns all of the files if 1 name matches https://i.gyazo.com/89b5a8ad17e427c009e1289e8708d840.png

Comment: @pat your original code would also return all nested files for each file. I have updated the code for what you want